# I'm having a very specific problem with OpenCV 3 in cvtColor and I've tried the previous solutions but none of them worked

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I'm facing the following error:

```
File "rropcode.py", line 35, in <module>
imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(entrada, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)    
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:10705: error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) in function cvtColor
```

I've already tried the other solutions to this topic but none of them work.

Here is my code

```
import cv2  
import time  
import numpy as np  
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

Hmin = 42  
Hmax = 92  
Smin = 62  
Smax = 255  
Vmin = 63  
Vmax = 235  

rangeMin = np.array([Hmin, Smin, Vmin], np.uint8)  
rangeMax = np.array([Hmax, Smax, Vmax], np.uint8)  

minArea = 50  

cv2.namedWindow("Entrada")  
cv2.namedWindow("HSV")  
cv2.namedWindow("Thre")  
cv2.namedWindow("Erosao")  

width = 160  
height = 120  

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  

if capture.isOpened():  
    capture.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)  
    capture.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)  


while True:  
      ret, entrada = capture.read()  
       # I'M HAVING AN ISSUE IN THE NEXT LINE  
      **imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(entrada, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)**     
      imgThresh = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, rangeMin, rangeMax)  
      imgErode = cv2.erode(imgThresh, None, iterations = 3)
```

The line marked in bold is throwing the above error.

Comment: What solutions have you tried and why did they not work?

Comment: Does imshow() on entrada (without any processing) work?

Comment: @J.D. imshow() is not working

Comment: @MadPhysicist essentially, what I read was, that there is some problem with the dimensions of the of the image or with the path that it is stored using. Some very weird stuff I haven't heard about. Please help me out.

Comment: Did you check `capture.isOpened()==True`?

Comment: This may seem silly, but does the camera work on your pi? Have you tested it with other software? If it does work, it may be that cv2.VideoCapture(0) does not return your camera. Check this with `print(capture.isOpened())`.

Comment: After `capture.read()` please check if the the returned mat is not None before any processing as: `if entrada is not None: print "success"`

Comment: @J.D. my camera is working, no issues with that.

Comment: @QuangHoang nah, that's not working

Comment: @ZdaR still trying not working mate. Could you tell me the exact code?

Comment: Is it necessary that i use an external webcam with cv2.VideoCapture()?

Comment: The majority of usual image souces (web cam or IP camera) produce colors in BGR  order, not RGB. But some devices can produce some more complicated images (something like YV12 compression inside BMP file). And in this case you'll probably get an ASSERT. Could you place here the example of your input image? Just use imwrite function inside your code

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit to long to handle in the comments, so I'll temporarily do it here. Can you test this code and tell if you see an image or which of the print statements you see?

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np  

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
if capture.isOpened():
    print("Camera openend")
    ret, img = capture.read()  
    if ret:
        print("Image read")
        cv2.imshow("img", img)    
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```